# Change wallpaper properties in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization, display-settings

I have a picture to put wallpaper. Picture position is center. The image width is thinner than the width of the monitor. So, around the image is black.

But, I want around the image is white. What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on your desktop and choose "Personalise"

Click on the "Desktop Background" item.:
[image]

Check the "Picture Position" at the bottom, and then choose the "Change Background Colour" option. Click the white (or colour of your choice) box, OK, then "Save Changes"
[image]